# Are transducers blocking in core.async?

Tags: clojure, core.async

When using transducers on channels are the execution of that trasducer blocking the main thread?

For example `(chan 1 long-running-trans)`

Would this code delay the main thread until the execution is done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a channel doesn't per-se do anything on the main execution thread, as the transducer will only get into effect once you put things into the channel.

When you do, there are different consequences from a thread occupation point of view, depending on whether you're running over the JVM or on a JS runtime:

### JVM

In the following block:

```
(let [pipe (chan 1 long-running-trans)]
  (go
    (>! pipe "stuff"))
  (go
    (let [stuff (<! pipe)]
      (println stuff))))
```

Whatever code appears within the `go` blocks will be [executed within a dedicate threadpool](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/a6dc01d2ebb692a39e923988b0853ff2bd1a431b/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/dispatch.clj#L18). As such, neither the put nor the get will keep your main thread busy.

If you were to use the blocking version of the channel operators ([`>!!`](https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/%3E!!) or [`<!!`](https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/%3C!!)), then you are explicitly asking the runtime to perform them on the main thread, and the transducer will hog your main thread any time you put (`>!!`) an element into the channel.

### JS

When you run on a JS engine, you have only one thread of execution and the non-blocking version of the channel operators (`>!` and `<!`). Thus, your transducers will indeed affect your main and only thread. Execution would then follow the normal rules of the [JS event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).